# How does Xquery work on the server

Tags: xquery

I'm not sure how does the Xquery works on the server. I know the syntax,but not sure how to implement it for my site.

For example. I have site that stored the username and password in XML file. Now I want to verify the username and password for log in or sign up.

How can I do this? Do I just write a Xquery file and upload to the server and then call it?

Comment: What XQuery processor are you using? There are many out there and the most important ones support REST or RestXQ, for example BaseX, eXist and MarkLogic do. Especially RestXQ is suitable for writing server-side XQuery.

Comment: I'm using Sausalito. What do you mean by server side Xquery?

Answer (score 1):

Please find below an example of a basic authentication module that runs on top of Sausalito.

```
module namespace auth = "[project logical uri]lib/auth";

import module namespace base64 = "http://www.zorba-xquery.com/modules/converters/base64";

import module namespace req = "http://www.28msec.com/modules/http/request";
import module namespace res = "http://www.28msec.com/modules/http/response";

declare variable $auth:login := "login";
declare variable $auth:password := "password";

declare function auth:authorize() as empty-sequence()
{
 let $auth := "Basic " || string(base64:encode($html:login || ":" || $html:password)) eq  req:header-value("Authorization")
 return
  if(not($auth) and not($unprotected)) then
    error($res:unauthorized);
  else
    (); 
};
```

Comment: Thank you. so I have a Xquery file like this and then just upload the file to the server.